# How to print arabic characters to zebra lp 2824 plus printer using java programming language

Tags: java, printing, arabic, zebra-printers, zpl

I am trying to print arabic text using java but tha label comes empty every time

```
String commands = "^XA\n" + 
            "^LH 10,10\n" + "^FO40,12\n" + "^ADN,35,10\n" + "^FDname: " + patient.name + "^FS\n" +
            "^LH0,0\n" + "^LH 10,10\n" + "^FO40,55\n" + "^ADN,35,10\n" + "^FDnumber: " + patient.number + "^FS\n" +
            "^LH0,0\n" + "^LH 10,10\n" + "^FO40,95\n" + "^ADN,35,10\n" + "^FDrotba: " + patient.degree + "^FS\n" +
            "^XZ";
DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;
            Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(commands.getBytes(), flavor, null);
            try {
                job.print(doc, null);
            } catch (PrintException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
```

Comment: Did you try non-arabic characters? do they show?

Comment: Just realized that this is an old question. It would be useful if you add the solution to the problem you faces, if you have already solved it.